# Connect multiple clients using single thread with synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, asynchronous

a few months ago,i had asked some relative questions about qt tcp network programming for my project. And finally the software  came out. But after learned more detail about qt `event mechans` and `signals -slots`  realization. I have some worry about my program performance and stability.

The key problem is that server using a single thread for handle multiple tcpsockets. the brief introduction code for realization:

1. `incomingConnection` function  is writen as following: two `QSignalMapper` are used for map each socket `SlotReadyRead` and `SlotDisconnected`

```c++
void ServerModule::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
 {
    m_tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    if (!m_tcpSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
        return;
    }
    connect(m_tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), m_readyReadSignalMapper, SLOT(map()));
     m_readyReadSignalMapper->setMapping(m_tcpSocket, m_tcpSocket);
     connect(m_tcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), m_disconnectedSignalMapper, SLOT(map()));
     m_disconnectedSignalMapper->setMapping(m_tcpSocket, m_tcpSocket);
     }
```

2. the sever construct function:

```c++
ServerModule::ServerModule(QObject * parent) : QTcpServer(parent),m_readyReadSignalMapper(new QSignalMapper(this)),m_disconnectedSignalMapper(new QSignalMapper(this))
{

    connect(m_readyReadSignalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QObject *)), this, SLOT(SlotReadyRead(QObject *)));
    connect(m_disconnectedSignalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QObject *)), this, SLOT(SlotDisconnected(QObject*)));
       ......other code 
}
```

3. `SlotReadyRead` and  `SlotDisconnected` functions are every normal,it converts`QObject* socketObject` to `QTcpSocket *socket` and then do some work.

So i have learned that if write like aboving `connect` function  with specific `connect  mode`

> Qt::DirectConnection
>   Qt::QueuedConnection
>   Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection

if using single thread,only first mode and second mode can be used . And use first mode, it's  ***synchronous***  ,if second, it's ***asynchronous***. My program default  using first mode, so the `signals -slots` are connected  ***synchronous***.

So here is my worry:
1. How about the single thread performance  for handling  multiple sockets?can it reach 500 connection /per second concurrency?what's  the max connected can be handled?
2. if at the same time,multiple sockets are ready to read then called qt core to send `readyRead` signals, the `QSignalMapper` can handle it properly?
3. should I connect `socket` and `QSignalMapper` using ***QueuedConnection***  mode, because this connecting  is not connected immediately, it's using `event queue` and `postEvent` to connect. so its ***asynchronous***. Is in this situation,the concurrency request  can be handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a few issues with your code:

1. QSignalMapper just adds complexity to your code
2. Don't use a member variable for QTcpSocket, you will be overwriting it every time and chances are that you might use an invalid pointer
3. If you are not doing something complex or using QSslSocket don't subclass QTcpServer, just connect to the newConnection() signal and call nextPendingConnection()

Now to the connect part of your questioning you should read https://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html in short:

- Qt::DirectConnection - means once the signal is emitted the slot will called immediately, if the object that has the slot lives in another thread it will be called in the caller thread. This is used if Qt::AutoConnection is used and both objects live in the same thread.
- Qt::QueuedConnection - means that when the signal is emitted it will create an event and be put on the event loop to be dispatched once you return to the event loop, this is useful for different threads as the slot will called on the thread that the object lives in. This is NOT what you want here, nor how QTcpSocket should be used (read the docs).
- Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection - is very rare to use this one, this like the above puts the event on the event loop of the other thread, but it blocks until the slot was called.

The only "Sync" method is the blocking one, because it would block, but that doesn't mean it's a problem, you can have a non-gui thread that blocks waiting for the reply of the gui thread while asking the user for a password for example.

To the questions now:

#### UPDATED 1 and 3 for more clarification

1. Performance really depends on what these sockets will do, how long each will take to process the request and send a reply, in [Cutelyst Web Framework](http://www.cutelyst.org) a single thread on an i5 can process up to 100K req/s (returning a 'Hello Wolrd!' string HTTP response), the maximum number depends of concurrent connections will be limited by max ports available, memory available to allocate memory and of course if it's CPU intensive the clients will have a long time waiting.

The most common way is to call sender() on your slot, due a *small hit* on performance (due sender() call) it's faster to use a lambda:

```
void Parser::readyRead() {
     auto socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
     ...
}
```

Or with a lambda:

```
connect(sock, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, [sock] () {
    // use sock obj here
});
```

2. Again QSignalMapper is not what you want, you should call sender() to get the QTcpSocket or use a lambda capturing the socket object (this is a little faster)
3. No shouldn't used QueuedConnection connection on your QSignalMapper, because that will cause an unneeded overhead due the fact that it will put the event on the event loop queue and it will be processed later, it might also cause weird bugs due the way QTcpSockets handle data (you **must** consume all the bytesAvailable() on readyReady since if no extra data arrives readyRead() signal is not emitted again.

Comment: thanks for your answer.but i still have some questions:1. if not use QSignalMapper ,how can i pass the tcpsocket pointer to slots function?  2. what's the meaning of "no use DirectConnection"?i think my code default use "DirectConnection" mode.

Comment: Great answer ! The use of sender() made my day. I was totally stuck in the member variable hell with QTcpSocket. Thanks